# Uncaught ReferenceError: wp is not defined in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, visual-composer, wp-admin

i have `edit or add new page` on `wordpress ken theme` with `WPBakery Visual Composer` but it not load properly

its give error on `console`

> Uncaught ReferenceError: wp is not defined  at mk_upload_option
>   (admin-scripts.js:2)

image for better understand

[image]

i also done step like

1. clear cache
2. Deactive Active plugin
3. delete wpbakery visual composer and install new with same version

but it did not work

Comment: Did you have this error with the Visual Composer being deactivated?

Comment: yes all plugin and composer plugin deactive but error also come how to resolve i try my best but any result so plss any one tell me  how to resolve this problem @Blackbam

Comment: If you deactivte the Theme for a minute, is the error still ocurring then? Because it might be some problem with the Themes' code.

Comment: so what i need to change

Comment: Does the error still occur if you activate a different theme?

Comment: yes there is no any editor in post edit page and error still come

Comment: It looks like your visual editor is somehow broken. Find out why and you find the problem.

Comment: i try all but not solve than i ask question in SO

Comment: I cant debug it for you. If you deactivate all Plugins AND the Theme and it STILL does not work, make a WordPress bug report

Comment: Hello @BhargavChudasama Did you find the solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: change the php version and its solve

Answer (score 1):

This could be the result of plugin conflicts, such as Autoptimize or Async Javascript.

I would first try to put the following in the "exclude" section of Autoptimize, and the issue might well go away.

`wp-includes/js`

If the issue persists, I would exclude the following in both plugins:

```
wp-includes/js/dist/, wp-includes/js/tinymce/, js/jquery/jquery.js, js/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help.

Use customizer's `js` file array dependency as `customize-preview` while enqueuing.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'customizer', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/customizer.js', array( 'customize-preview' ), '1.0', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was due to plugin conflicts. I used **Elementor** and
**ThemeREX Addons**.

I discovered the problem by deactivating the plugins one by one and checking in the Chrome Console when the errors disappeared.
The two of the above plugins have conflicts for loading jQuery.

So I decided to **Deactivate** the **ThemeREX Addons** and that worked for me.

**Note that!!!** If your plugin has **exclude options** it is better to use it and exclude already included scripts (from other plugins) because deactivating some of the plugins isn't the best decision in every case.

Another action that works is to edit the **header.php file** and add a link to the jQuery file at the top of the `<head></head>` section. But that edit will be overridden when a new update of the theme is created and you decide to update your theme and you will need to edit the file again. Note that if you forget to edit it again some important functions on your website could stop working. So **DON'T EDIT THIS FILE**.

Cheers.